# inconsistent timing in async discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

im trying to make a discord bot send a message every 30 miniutes, the only solution i could come up with gets very weird, it will start sending messages at seemingly random intervals and send multiple at once.

here is the affected code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await test()

async def test():       
    print("running test")
    channel = client.get_channel(PLACEHOLDER)
    await channel.send("i like " +words)
    print(words)
    await asyncio.sleep(1800)
    await test()
```

i have tried replacing asyncio.sleep with time.sleep but that causes the bot to time out and run the test() function from both on_ready and itself causing it to send messages twice, i'll be it on a consistent basis. me and a couple friends have been messing with it for a while and can't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`discord.ext.task.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task#discord.ext.tasks.loop):

```py
from discord.ext import task

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")
    await test.start()

@task.loop(minutes=30)
async def test():
    print("30 minutes have passed")
```

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name 'task' from 'discord.ext' (unknown location)`
i have absolutley no idea why its saying this , i can import `discord.ext import commands` just fine.


EDIT: 1. the import is tasks not task. 2. i had to put `task = discord.ext.tasks` to get it to work.

Comment: i had to add `test.start()` to on_ready. but it works now, thanks!